# Prevent Scratch from making files with tilde

Tags: code

Everytime I edit something in Scratch, it creates a file with the same name ending with a tilde (~).

How can I prevent this? This is really annoying while working with Git.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although not a direct resolution to your problem, you should probably add tilde files to your .gitignore file anyways. This will prevent git from even noticing them, and should solve your problem.

You can read about the format and contents of the .gitignore file [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore).

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks for this answer, this solved the problem. I've made a global .gitignore file with '*~' in it.

Comment: Glad that I could help out!

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have the file open and are currently editing it. Once you close Scratch this should disappear.

Answer (score 0):

You won't see the tilde file if you disable "show hidden files" in Files or disable "save files when changed" in Scratch.